# How to disable pylint no-self-use warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I'm coding in Python3 and using pylint to keep my code clean.

I want to define something like interface class, so I could add more functionality in a clean and concise way, however, pylint gets in the way of this goal.

Here's a sample method:

```
def on_enter(self, dummy_game, dummy_player): #pylint disable=no-self-use
    """Defines effects when entering area."""
    return None
```

Here's pylint output:

```
R: 70, 4: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
```

The question is:

1. How do I suppress warning (notice the `#pylint` comment)? or
2. How do I tell pylint that this is merely an interface (notice the `dummy_game` and `dummy_player`

EDIT:
Output of `pylint --version`:

```
pylint 1.2.1, 
astroid 1.1.1, common 0.61.0
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are currently ignoring this as

```
def on_enter(self, dummy_game, dummy_player): #pylint disable=no-self-use
    ...
```

Instead do

```
# pylint: disable=R0201
def on_enter(self, dummy_game, dummy_player): 
    ...
```

---

Add a comment to your file like below

```
# pylint: disable=R0201
```

You can find the short codes mnemonics to for each of the warnings/errors on [documentation here](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id21):

> `no-self-use (R0201)`:
>
> Method could be a function Used when a method doesn’t use its bound instance, and so could be written as a function.

In case the whole file contains code for the interface only, you can put this at the top:

```
# pylint: disable=R0201
class SomeInterface(object):
    ...
    ...
```

In case you have other code as well, and want to disable this for the interface class only, you can enable the check again like

```
# pylint: disable=R0201
class SomeInterface(object):
    ...
    ...

# pylint: enable=R0201

class AnotherClass(object):
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: All three cases are ignored by pylint: `#pylint disable=R0201` and `#pylint disable=no-self-use` before the class and both `#pylint disable=R0201` with `#pylint disable=no-self-use`. I prefer using full warning (`no-self-use`) instead of code (`R0201`), because it's easier to see what's supressed.

Comment: @julka I think you might be on an older version of pylint, try using `# pylint: disable-msg=R0201` instead. FWIW, on my system if I use `# pylint: disable-msg=R0201`, it throws up another deprecation warning.

Comment: Again ignored. Output of `pylint --version` is put into question.

Comment: @julka Just noticed in your post. You need to put that comment in a fresh line of its own, not in continuation of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems that I'm using an indeed older version of pylint. Quick check at pylint website said that current version is 1.4, while my system only has 1.2.1 (and is even built against python2). Now I only need to find how to tell Ubuntu package manager to download pylint 1.4 and build it against python3

Comment: @julka So putting those pylint comments in a fresh line didn't work? In your example code currently, you put them in the same line as valid python code, so pylint won't catch them. I don't think this is a version specific issue.

Comment: Pylint did catch them: it said I have 0 comments (which is indeed true, if we exclude doc strings and pylint suppreses)

Comment: @julka It caught them and still threw up that `no-self-use` error? incredible.

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question otherwise. Yes, it caught (I think so) and yes, it throws (I see it).

Comment: kay, you were right, I finally managed to get latest pylint (following instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340940/installing-pylint-for-python3-on-ubuntu)), it still throws `no-self-use`.

Comment: God, I lacked colon: I used `pylint disable=no-self-use` when it should've been `pylint: disable=no-self-use`

Comment: @julka I see. I now realize that I was using the `:` in my examples, but didn't realize the difference in yours. Anyway, if that helped, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: But yours didn't answer the question, best I can give is an upvote, and so I will when I'll have enough rep. Kay, they did, me stupey.

Answer (score 31):

Turns out I was lacking colon :

I used
`pylint disable=no-self-use`
when it should have been
`pylint: disable=no-self-use`

Well, at least I will always have the latest (and the one built for python3) pylint from now on :)